# Foundation Sticky not initializing properly on hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation, sticky

**BACKGROUND**: I have two tables of a sort (made using `li` tags) with sticky headers. One starts hidden, and the other is shown immediately. This is the sticky implementation that I use for both of them (with different id's obviously)

```
<div id="listContainer">
    <div class="row" data-sticky-container>
        <div id="stickyMenu" class="columns small-12 show-for-medium" data-sticky data-sticky-on="small" data-margin-top="0" data-anchor="listContainer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="columns small-12">
                    <div style="background-color: #96d1f2; padding: .5rem 1rem">
                        <div class="row text-center">
                            <!-- Header Stuff -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns small-12">
            <div style="border: 1px solid #96d1f2;">
                <ul class="no-bullet" id="partList" style="margin: 0;">
                    <!-- List/Table Items -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

The one that is hidden, is simply hidden the same way jQuery does it with `display: none;` in the style attribute.

No matter which one I choose to start hidden, the other one always ends up with a header that's all the way squished to the left, and no stickiness.

The tables are shown/hidden using jQuery when the user selects something from a dropdown - for simplicity's sake. We may end up using radio buttons or something else, but this is how it is in development and not part of the question.

**QUESTION**: Why is this happening, and how can I fix it or work around it?

**THINGS I'VE ALREADY TRIED**: I already tried to hide it after initializing the sticky part. As in, I tried to hide it once the custom javascript for the page loaded instead of setting it to be hidden from the very start. That still didn't work.

Comment: Will you include the css of the markup above? Thanks.

Comment: That's basically it. In the header, there's some padding on another div, and a background-color. I'll include that. The table itself is pretty complicated.